# График относительных частот в R

Tags: r, график, rstudio

Мне нужно построить гистограмму относительных частот через plot. Я знаю, что для построения гистограммы выборки используется функция hist(). Чтобы построить гистограмму относительных частот в параметры добавляется freq=FALSE и сумма частот на графике должна быть равна 1. 
Почему-то при использовании freq=FALSE сумма относительных частот на графике превышает 1. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка и как ее исправить?[image: гистограмма абсолютных частот]

[image: гистограмма относительных частот]

Answer (score 0):

Потому что есть нормализация по сумме частот, и нормализация (классическая) по сумме площадей. Это не ошибка, а просто разные вещи. Вы используете метод, при который приводит к единице площадь (высота*ширину интервала). Я не помню уже как это делается в R, но в Python решение есть через использования соответствующих весов (параметров weight). Ищите в R нечто подобное.